# Comparing Two Substring of Two Arrays that contain css property using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to swap css of an element and display it to user..
For Eg:

```
#box{background-color:#ccc; float:left}  // original css
```

The user then change the `bg-color` say to `#008000` which will be `inline` to `#box`.

so the new css will be `#box{background-color:#008000; float:left}`

Below is the code which I'm using for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Experimenting</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #box{float:left; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#008000; border:1px solid #ccc}
    .panel{float:right; width:350px; padding:0 10px}
    .panel h3{font-size:20px; line-height:30px; color:#666; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC}
    .panel p, h4{font-size:16px; color:#343434; padding:10px 0 10px 20px}
    .panel h4{font-weight:normal; padding-top:0; text-align:center}
    .panel p input{width:70px; height:20px; border:1px solid #000; padding:0 5px}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="box" class="clearfix"><p>Hellloooo....</p></div>
     <div class="panel">
         <p>Background-color: <input type="text" class="color" id="boxbg" value="ffffff"></p>
         <p>Border: <select type="text" id="brwid">
            <option value="0px">0px</option>
            <option value="1px" selected="selected">1px</option>
            <option value="2px">2px</option>
            <option value="3px">3px</option>
            <option value="4px">4px</option>
            <option value="5px">5px</option>
          </select>
                <select type="text" id="brstyl">
                        <option value="solid" selected="selected">Solid</option>
                        <option value="dotted">Dotted</option>
                        <option value="dashed">Dashed</option>
                        <option value="double">Double</option>
                        <option value="none">none</option>
                 </select>
                <input type="text" class="color" id="brclr" value="d4d2cb"></p>

                <input type="button" value="get css" id="code" />
       </div>
       <p id="demo" class="clearfix">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#boxbg').change(function(){
    var boxbg = "#"+$('#boxbg').val();
    $('#box').css('background-color',boxbg);
});

$('#brwid,#brstyl,#brclr').change(function(){
    var brwid = $('#brwid').val();
    var brstyl = $('#brstyl').val();
    var brcolr = "#"+$('#brclr').val();
    var bordr = brwid +" " + brstyl +" "+brcolr;
    $('#box').css('border',bordr);
}
);

$('#code').click(function(){
    var org_css = getElementChildrenAndStyles('#box');
    var chng_css = document.getElementById('box').style.cssText;
    org_css = org_css.replace('background-position:','');
    org_css = org_css.replace('background-repeat:','');
    var intIndexOfMatch;
    while (intIndexOfMatch != -1){
    // Replace out the current instance.
    org_css = org_css.replace('initial initial;','');
    // Get the index of any next matching substring.
    intIndexOfMatch = org_css.indexOf( "initial initial;" );
    }

    //getting only css property
    var open_curl = org_css.indexOf( "{" );
    open_curl = open_curl+1;
    var close_curl = org_css.indexOf( "}" );
    var org_css = org_css.substring(open_curl,close_curl);
    //alert(org_css+"<br>"+chng_css);

    var start,end,prop,value,a;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="";
    var old_css=org_css.split(";");
    var inln_csss=chng_css.split(";");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "The original css: "+ org_css +"<br><br>The New css: ";
    for(i=0; i<old_css.length-1;i++)
    {
      start = old_css[i].indexOf(":")+1;
      end = old_css[i].length;
      prop = old_css[i].substring(0,start);
      value = old_css[i].substring(start,end);
      //a = "The css is: "+old_css[i]+"<br>"+" property is-   "+prop+"   value is-  "+value+"<br><br>";
        for(j=0; j<inln_csss.length-1;j++)
        {
          var c_start = inln_csss[j].indexOf(":")+1;
          var c_end = inln_csss[j].length;
          var c_prop = inln_csss[j].substring(0,c_start);
          var c_value = inln_csss[j].substring(c_start,c_end);
          //var c_a = "The css is: "+inln_csss[j]+"<br>"+" property is-   "+c_prop+"   value is-  "+c_value+"<br><br>";
          //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "The Changed Css are as follows:<br><br>"+c_a;
          var new_arr = inln_csss.length;
          alert("elements in arr: "+new_arr+" /"+prop);
          if(c_prop==prop)
          {
              alert(prop+" === "+c_prop);
              old_css[i] = inln_csss[j];
          }
        }
        if(i==old_css.length-1)
        {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += old_css[i];
        }
        else{document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += old_css[i]+";";}
    }
});



function getElementChildrenAndStyles(selector) {
  selector = selector.split(",").map(function(subselector){
    return subselector + "," + subselector + " *";
  }).join(",");
  elts = $(selector);

  var rulesUsed = [];
  // main part: walking through all declared style rules
  // and checking, whether it is applied to some element
  sheets = document.styleSheets;
  for(var c = 0; c < sheets.length; c++) {
    var rules = sheets[c].rules || sheets[c].cssRules;
    for(var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
      var selectorText = rules[r].selectorText;
      var matchedElts = $(selectorText);
      for (var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
        if (matchedElts.index(elts[i]) != -1) {
          rulesUsed.push(rules[r]); break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var style = rulesUsed.map(function(cssRule){
    /*if ($.browser.msie) {
      var cssText = cssRule.style.cssText.toLowerCase();
    } else {*/
      var cssText = cssRule.cssText;
    //}
    // some beautifying of css
    return cssText.replace(/(\{|;)\s+/g, "\$1\n  ").replace(/\A\s+}/, "}");
    //                 set indent for css here ^ 
  }).join("\n");
  return style;
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

I'm unable to compare the two values, the values are getting stored perfectly then to the `if` statement always return `false`
i.e:

```
if(c_prop==prop){
     old_css[i] = inln_csss[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.css()` method:

```
element.css('background-color', '#008000');
```

It will take care of setting `element.style` property for you.

---

**Edit:** If you have many elements for which the CSS property should be changed, you can:

1. Use CSS selector
2. Pass an array of elements instead of single element

Ad 1.

The following will change background color of all child elements of `<div id="container">...</div>`.

```
$('#container div').css('background-color', '#008000');
```

Ad 2.

The following will do the same:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('div');
$(elements).css('background-color', 'green');
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TP3kX/) for an example.

Comment: nice idea @kamituel  but i want to display that code to user.. basically i m creating an interface in which user can modify the styling of an element and then get the code which will include both changed property and old one too

Comment: @WannaLearn - yes, it's much cleaner, because you don't mix JS with CSS. If it solves your issue, please accept my answer.

Comment: For eg: user can change the color but not the float,height or width                 so when the user change the color , the user will get those unchangable property with the changed color..                         hope u understand what i need

Comment: @WannaLearn - I see. Have you considered using `.css()`? (see updated answer)

Comment: I have used only 1 element in my eg, but there are 'n' numbers of elements and specifying css property for each is too long method...

Comment: @WannaLearn - you can use it to change CSS of every element from an array. See updaten answer.

Comment: Thanx for help... The error was it was talking space so before comparing i just used  c_prop = $.trim(c_prop); prop = $.trim(prop); and now its working... :)